# How to fetch data based on scrolling of div - JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am working on a search page wherein I could potentially get thousands of records (I fetch Client Name only) based on search criteria. I load the data into a results div (height:300px; overflow:scroll). Is it possible to fetch a part of data first (kind of paging) and bring the next part when the user scrolls the div? I don't want to implement paging again since I already have paging implemented for a grid in the previous page. And please let me know your views if this is required too.

Any idea would be of great help.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible way of doing it based off an example shown [here](http://yelotofu.com/2008/10/jquery-how-to-tell-if-youre-scroll-to-bottom/) for how to check if you're scrolled to the bottom. It checks every second to see whether to send a POST request for the new "page". You could add things like setting the interval on `mouseenter` and clearing it on `mouseleave` so it's not checking every second someone is on your page, but this should give you a basic idea.

JS:

```
var checkBottom, page = 1;

function ifBottom(){
   var cont = $('#container');

   if(cont.scrollHeight - cont.scrollTop() == cont.outerHeight()){
      page = page++;
      $.post('example.php', {pg: page}, function(html){
         cont.append(html);
      }, 'html');
   }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   checkBottom = setInterval(ifBottom(), 1000);
});
```